# Where do I find the full list of shortcuts used in Linux Virtual Console (Terminal)?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, virtual-console

I know only <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> to switch between consoles and scroll the screen by <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd>/<kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

Is there a full list of shortcuts specifically for the virtual console?

Comment: It depends on the shell :-P These 14 work with bash: https://linuxhandbook.com/linux-shortcuts/ ... edit: an even longer list https://skorks.com/2009/09/bash-shortcuts-for-maximum-productivity/

Comment: Switching between consoles is certainly not dependent on the shell, although scrolling is. So the comment by @Rinzwind doesn't fully answer the question.

Comment: @BobDoolittle Comments are *not* intended to fully answer a question, see https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/19076/250300.